# Updating wallpaper by the date in muzei similar app

Tags: javascript, android, date, live-wallpaper, muzei

I've developed a wallpaper by using muzei codes (open source - https://github.com/romannurik/muzei/) but have an awkward problem about updating the wallpapers.

I used a local source instead of an api or db in a host. So i changed the FeautedArtSource.java like this;

```js
package com.google.android.apps.muzei.featuredart;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.apps.muzei.api.Artwork;
import com.google.android.apps.muzei.api.RemoteMuzeiArtSource;
import com.google.android.apps.muzei.api.UserCommand;
import com.google.android.apps.muzei.util.IOUtil;
import com.google.android.apps.muzei.util.LogUtil;

import com.xxx.xxx.BuildConfig;
import com.xxx.xxx.R;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import static com.google.android.apps.muzei.util.LogUtil.LOGD;
import static com.google.android.apps.muzei.util.LogUtil.LOGE;
import static com.google.android.apps.muzei.util.LogUtil.LOGW;

public class FeaturedArtSource extends RemoteMuzeiArtSource {
    private static final String TAG = LogUtil.makeLogTag(FeaturedArtSource.class);
    private static final String SOURCE_NAME = "FeaturedArt";

    private static  String QUERY_URL = "file:///android_asset/starrynight.jpg";
    private static  Uri ARCHIVE_URI = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/starrynight.jpg");

    private static final int COMMAND_ID_SHARE = 1;
    private static final int COMMAND_ID_VIEW_ARCHIVE = 2;
    private static final int COMMAND_ID_DEBUG_INFO = 51;

    private static final int MAX_JITTER_MILLIS = 1 * 60 * 1000;

    private static Random sRandom = new Random();

    private static final SimpleDateFormat sDateFormatTZ
            = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    private static final SimpleDateFormat sDateFormatLocal
            = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    static {
        sDateFormatTZ.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }

    public FeaturedArtSource() {

        super(SOURCE_NAME);
    }

    public  void urls()
    {


        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==1)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image1.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image1.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==2)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image2.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image2.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==3)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image3.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image3.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==4)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image4.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image4.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==5)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image5.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image5.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==6)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image6.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image6.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==7)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image7.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image7.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==8)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image8.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image8.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==9)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image9.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image9.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==10)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image10.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image10.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==11)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image11.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image11.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==12)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image12.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image12.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==13)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image13.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image13.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==14)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image14.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image14.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==15)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image15.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image15.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==16)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image16.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image16.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==17)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image17.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image17.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==18)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image18.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image18.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==19)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image19.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image19.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==20)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image20.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image20.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==21)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image21.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image21.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==22)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image22.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image22.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==23)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image23.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image23.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==24)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image24.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image24.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==25)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image25.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image25.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==26)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image26.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image26.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==27)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image27.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image27.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==28)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image28.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image28.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==29)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image29.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image29.jpg");
        }
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)==30)
        {
            QUERY_URL="file:///android_asset/image30.jpg";
            ARCHIVE_URI=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/image30.jpg");
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(int reason) {

        urls();
        List<UserCommand> commands = new ArrayList<>();
        if (reason == UPDATE_REASON_INITIAL) {
            // Show initial photo (starry night)
            publishArtwork(new Artwork.Builder()
                    .imageUri(Uri.parse(QUERY_URL))
                    .title("xxx")
                    .token("xxx")
                    .byline("xxx")
                    .viewIntent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse(QUERY_URL)))
                    .build());
            commands.add(new UserCommand(BUILTIN_COMMAND_ID_NEXT_ARTWORK));
            // show the latest photo in 15 minutes
            scheduleUpdate(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000);

        } else {
            // For everything but the initial update, defer to RemoteMuzeiArtSource
            super.onUpdate(reason);
        }

        commands.add(new UserCommand(COMMAND_ID_SHARE, getString(R.string.action_share_artwork)));

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            commands.add(new UserCommand(COMMAND_ID_DEBUG_INFO, "Debug info"));
        }
        setUserCommands(commands);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSubscriberAdded(ComponentName subscriber) {
        super.onSubscriberAdded(subscriber);
        Artwork currentArtwork = getCurrentArtwork();
        if (currentArtwork != null && !"initial".equals(currentArtwork.getToken())) {
            // TODO: is this really necessary?
            // When a subscriber is added, manually try a fetch, unless this is the
            // first update
            onUpdate(UPDATE_REASON_OTHER);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCustomCommand(int id) {
        super.onCustomCommand(id);
        urls();
        if (COMMAND_ID_SHARE == id) {
            Artwork currentArtwork = getCurrentArtwork();
            if (currentArtwork == null) {

                LOGW(TAG, "No current artwork, can't share.");
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(FeaturedArtSource.this,
                                R.string.featuredart_source_error_no_artwork_to_share,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                return;
            }

            String detailUrl = ("initial".equals(currentArtwork.getToken()))
                    ? QUERY_URL
                    : currentArtwork.getViewIntent().getDataString();
            String artist = currentArtwork.getByline()
                    .replaceFirst("\\.\\s*($|\\n).*", "").trim();

            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My Android wallpaper today is '"
                    + currentArtwork.getTitle().trim()
                    + "' by " + artist
                    + ". #MuzeiFeaturedArt\n\n"
                    + detailUrl);
            shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share artwork");
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(shareIntent);

        } else if (COMMAND_ID_VIEW_ARCHIVE == id) {
            Intent viewArchiveIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, ARCHIVE_URI);
            viewArchiveIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            try {
                startActivity(viewArchiveIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ignored) {
            }

        } else if (COMMAND_ID_DEBUG_INFO == id) {
            long nextUpdateTimeMillis = getSharedPreferences()
                    .getLong("scheduled_update_time_millis", 0);
            final String nextUpdateTime;
            if (nextUpdateTimeMillis > 0) {
                Date d = new Date(nextUpdateTimeMillis);
                nextUpdateTime = SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(d);
            } else {
                nextUpdateTime = "None";
            }

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(FeaturedArtSource.this,
                            "Next update time: " + nextUpdateTime,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTryUpdate(int reason) throws RetryException {

        Artwork currentArtwork = getCurrentArtwork();
       /* Artwork artwork;
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            jsonObject = IOUtil.fetchJsonObject(QUERY_URL);
            artwork = Artwork.fromJson(jsonObject);
        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
            LOGE(TAG, "Error reading JSON", e);
            throw new RetryException(e);
        }

        if (artwork != null && currentArtwork != null && artwork.getImageUri() != null &&
                artwork.getImageUri().equals(currentArtwork.getImageUri())) {
            LOGD(TAG, "Skipping update of same artwork.");
        } else {
            LOGD(TAG, "Publishing artwork update: " + artwork);
            if (artwork != null && jsonObject != null) {
                publishArtwork(artwork);
            }
        }

        Date nextTime = null;
        String nextTimeStr = jsonObject.optString("nextTime");
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(nextTimeStr)) {
            int len = nextTimeStr.length();
            if (len > 4 && nextTimeStr.charAt(len - 3) == ':') {
                nextTimeStr = nextTimeStr.substring(0, len - 3) + nextTimeStr.substring(len - 2);
            }
            try {
                nextTime = sDateFormatTZ.parse(nextTimeStr);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                try {
                    sDateFormatLocal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                    nextTime = sDateFormatLocal.parse(nextTimeStr);
                } catch (ParseException e2) {
                    LOGE(TAG, "Can't schedule update; "
                            + "invalid date format '" + nextTimeStr + "'", e2);
                }
            }
        }

        boolean scheduleFallback = true;
        if (nextTime != null) {
            // jitter by up to N milliseconds
            scheduleUpdate(nextTime.getTime() + sRandom.nextInt(MAX_JITTER_MILLIS));
            scheduleFallback = false;
        }

        if (scheduleFallback) {
            // No next time, default to checking in 12 hours
            scheduleUpdate(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1 * 60 * 1000);
        }*/
        urls();
        publishArtwork(new Artwork.Builder()
                .imageUri(Uri.parse(QUERY_URL))
                .title("xxx")
                .token("xxx")
                .byline("xxx")
                .viewIntent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse(QUERY_URL)))
                .build());
        scheduleUpdate(System.currentTimeMillis()+1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && intent != null && "demoartwork".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            publishArtwork(new Artwork.Builder()
                    .imageUri(Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("image")))
                    .title(intent.getStringExtra("title"))
                    .token(intent.getStringExtra("image"))
                    .byline(intent.getStringExtra("byline"))
                    .viewIntent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse(QUERY_URL)))
                    .build());
            removeAllUserCommands();
        }

        super.onHandleIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

When i install it to the device it chooses the correct wallpaper for the specific day (for example: image 23 for september 23th) but the problem is; **it doesn't update the wallpaper for the next day.**

If i clear the data of the app from the device settings menu, it updates correctly.

Also if i change the date manually right after installing it to the device it works fine.

This is the Manifest file;

```js
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.xxx.xxx">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <!-- android:maxSdkVersion="18" /> ... has issues on some devices -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permissions required by the wearable app -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />

    <application android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.MuzeiApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.MuzeiActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MuzeiActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.MuzeiWallpaperService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" />
        </service>

        <service android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.SourceSubscriberService"
            android:exported="true" />

        <service android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.TaskQueueService" />

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.settings.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings_title"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Muzei.Settings"
            android:exported="true"
            android:parentActivityName="com.google.android.apps.muzei.MuzeiActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.settings.AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/about_title"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Muzei.About"
            android:parentActivityName="com.google.android.apps.muzei.settings.SettingsActivity" />

        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.NetworkChangeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Photo sources -->
        <service android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.featuredart.FeaturedArtSource"
            android:label="@string/featuredart_source_title"
            android:description="@string/featuredart_source_description"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_source_featured">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.api.MuzeiArtSource" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="color" android:value="#659fef" />
        </service>

        <service android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.gallery.GalleryArtSource"
            android:label="@string/gallery_source_title"
            android:description="@string/gallery_source_description"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_source_gallery">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.api.MuzeiArtSource" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="settingsActivity"
                android:value="com.google.android.apps.muzei.gallery.GallerySettingsActivity" />
            <meta-data android:name="color" android:value="#4db6ac" />
        </service>

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.gallery.GallerySettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/gallery_source_settings_title"
            android:parentActivityName="com.google.android.apps.muzei.settings.SettingsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Muzei.GallerySettings"
            android:exported="true" />

        <!-- Target for "Set As" intent -->

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.PhotoSetAsTargetActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/set_as_wallpaper_using_muzei">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ATTACH_DATA" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Watch for source package changes -->

        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.SourcePackageChangeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- New wallpaper notification receiver -->

        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.NewWallpaperNotificationReceiver" />

        <service android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.MuzeiWearableListenerService"
            tools:ignore="ExportedService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Aside from these files others are nearly same with the original muzei except for graphics, labels etc.

Any idea for the solution?